# What is the difference between calling the constructor with await and calling it with new in Mongo nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, driver

What is the difference between these two?

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
async function run() {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/testing', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).connect()
    // other code
  } finally {
    await client.close()
  }
}
run().catch(error => { console.error(error) })
```

and this:

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

async function run() {
  const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/testing', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  try {
    await client.connect()
    // other code
  } finally {
    await client.close()
  }
}
run().catch(error => { console.error(error) })
```

The documentation shows that the second one is the [official way](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html) of creating a client but I often find the first one to be used

Comment: You use `await` on `.connect()` in both cases, not on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The first usage puts the construction of the client under the try block. This does two things:

1. Any exceptions thrown by the constructor will be handled by the catch block.
2. The client object is scoped to the try block and isn't available in the catch block.

The most obvious consequence of this is that the clean up in the catch block won't ever work because client isn't defined there:

```
risque% node test.js
ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at run (/home/w/apps/tests/node-try-ctor/test.js:10:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```

You can test this by connecting to an incorrect port.